# Does Apple Watch 3 support Noise app?

Tags: apple-watch

I cannot find any reference on web that this app is only supported on new watches like 4 or 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Noise app requires Apple Watch Series 4 or later:

https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/noise-apd00a43a9cb/6.0/watchos/6.0